# how to display the html codes of a webpage specified by a URL using shell in Ubuntu?

Tags: shell, curl, wget

I want to display the html codes of a webpage specified by a URL using shell in Ubuntu? how could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cURL:

```
curl http://whatever.com
```

You may need to install curl tho -

```
apt-get install curl
```

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Stephen's answer, `wget` can do this too:

```
wget -q -O - http://example.com
```